Python: get output from inkscape run in shell mode
I run inkscape in shell mode from python, calling specific commands one by one on SVGs for performant conversion to PNG, like so:
process = subprocess.Popen([INKSCAPE_EXE_PATH, "--shell"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)

def create_image_data(SVGs):

    # Loop through all SVGs
    for svg in SVGs:
        # Create a temporary SVG file
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.svg') as temp_svg:
            temp_svg.write(svg.encode('utf-8'))
            temp_svg_path = temp_svg.name

        # Add commands to the list
        process.stdin.write(f"file-open:{temp_svg_path}\n")
        process.stdin.flush()  # Flush to ensure the command is sent

        # Export the image
        process.stdin.write(f"export-filename:{os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f'{filename}-{page}.png')}\n")
        process.stdin.write("export-do\n")
        process.stdin.flush()  # Make sure to flush the input buffer

        process.stdin.write("query-all\n")  # TODO get this output only
        process.stdin.flush()

    process.stdin.write("quit\n")


# Call the function with your input file
create_image_data(LIST_OF_SVGs)

I also need to extract bounding boxes. In shell mode, query-all prints all data to the shell conole. How can I obtain this data? process.stdout only has the "top-level shell prints"


In shell mode, query-all prints all data to the shell conole. How can I obtain this data? process.stdout only has the "top-level shell prints"

What you can try to continuously read from stdout and filter the output to capture the relevant information from the query-all command.
def read_output(process, expected_marker="SVG"):
    output = []

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        
        if not line:
            break

        output.append(line.strip())
    
        #  reach the end of the inkscape
        if expected_marker in line:
            break
    
    return output

def create_image_data(SVGs):
    process = subprocess.Popen([INKSCAPE_EXE_PATH, "--shell"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           text=True, shell=True)

    # Loop through all SVGs
    for idx, svg in enumerate(SVGs):
        filename = f"output_image_{idx}"
        page = idx


        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.svg') as temp_svg:
            temp_svg.write(svg.encode('utf-8'))
            temp_svg_path = temp_svg.name

        # Add commands to the list
        process.stdin.write(f"file-open:{temp_svg_path}\n")
        process.stdin.flush()  # Flush to ensure the command is sent

        # Export the image
        png_output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"{filename}-{page}.png")
        process.stdin.write(f"export-filename:{png_output_path}\n")
        process.stdin.write("export-do\n")
        process.stdin.flush()

        process.stdin.write("query-all\n")  # TODO get this output only
        process.stdin.flush()

        # Read and parse the output from query-all
        output = read_output(process, expected_marker="SVG")
        print(f"Bounding box info for {temp_svg_path}:")
        for line in output:
            print(line)

    process.stdin.write("quit\n")
    process.stdin.flush()
    process.wait()

create_image_data(LIST_OF_SVGs)

